# $emit causing browser to crash

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

We are using two directives to get different data from the server using http. We are sending $emit event to other directive and if user selecting other directive with speed $emit getting crashing here.

```
First Directive
  app.directive('dealStages', ['$filter', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function($filter, $rootScope, $timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: staticResourseUrl + '/html/pages/Deal/_deal-stages.html',
    scope: {
        'stages': '=',
        'id': '=',
        'scount': '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elemn, attr, rootScope) {
        scope.$watch('scount', function(newVal, oldVal) {});
        scope.$watch('stages', function(newVal, oldVal) {});
        scope.newContent = {};
        //scope.isChecked = utilSrv.isChecked;
        scope.getRadioChecked = scope.$parent.getRadioChecked;
        scope.loadQMDetails = function(e, qm) {
            ////console.log('inside load QM');
            $timeout(function() {
                //$scope.$broadcast("onSomething", "");
                scope.$emit('open', "true", e, qm);
            }, 1000);

            //scope.$broadcast('open', true, e);
            //scope.openQMModal = true;
        };

    }
}
}]);

Second Directive
app.directive('showQM', ['$rootScope', '$filter', '$timeout', '$window', '$document', '$location', 'dealService', 'utilSrv', 'errorModalService',
function($rootScope, $filter, $timeout, $window, $document, $location, dealService, utilSrv, errorModalService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            setFn: '&',
            getTimeline : '&',
            stages: '=',
            nextSteps: '=',
            notifications: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elemn, attr) {
            //  $rootScope.$broadcast('elastic:adjust');
            scope.activeStone;
            scope.callfromDirective = function(obj, qm){
                //console.log('inside');
                scope.qm_id = qm.id;
                scope.getAttachments(qm.id);
                scope.getQMNotes();
                scope.qmDetails = qm;
                scope.qmDetails.deadlineFormat = $filter('date')(scope.qmDetails.deadline, 'd MMM, yyyy');
                scope.editQM = scope.qmDetails;
                //console.log('==== before qmDetails====' + JSON.stringify(scope.qmDetails));
                //console.log('==== before qmDetails 3333====' + JSON.stringify(scope.editQM));
                scope.showDetailsDiv(obj);
            };

            $rootScope.$on('open', function(someData, e, obj, qm) {
                //////console.log('whole stone'+JSON.stringify(qm));
                scope.qm_id = qm.id;
                scope.getAttachments(qm.id);
                scope.getQMNotes();
                //scope.Label = false; 
                scope.qmDetails = qm;
                scope.qmDetails.deadlineFormat = $filter('date')(scope.qmDetails.deadline, 'd MMM, yyyy');
                scope.editQM = scope.qmDetails;
                console.log('show the values'+JSON.stringify(qm));
                scope.showDetailsDiv(obj);
                //$(".noteEdittextarea").flexible();
            });

}
```

]);

first directive creating here different div in the loop and user can click on open modal window on clicking on each div using second directive. If user simply open a modal window and do some operation there and quickly click on other div to open new modal then its breaking.

Comment: Define "crash", precisely. Tell what the problem is, and post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Could you provide a working Plunkr? Anything that you might be passing to your isolated scope might be causing the stack overflow (assuming that is the kind of browser crash that's happening). 

If you're on Chrome, you can enable error logging and go to `chrome://crashes`

Comment: Browser crashes are normally caused by infinite loops. Check for them in your code.

Comment: Its actually kind of memory leak. If a HTTP request in on the way and other request initiate with scope.$emit then memory leak happening. I am using two directive and sending emit from one to other. any idea what causing the issue.